# Form drop down selected baed on URL - pass variable

Tags: php, forms

I have this code:

```
<label for=subject accesskey=S>Subject</label>
<select name="subject" type="text" id="subject">
<option value="a dog">Dog</option>
<option value="a cat">Car</option>
<option value="a tree">Tree</option>
</select>
```

If I wanted to preselect a selection via the URL,

Would it not be:

`http://xxx.com/contactus.php?subject=a cat`

I have tried the above and it does not work.

I have had a look around and there are posts about adding Java Script. I wish to avoid that if possible.

Comment: well the space must be encoded with %20 ?

Comment: I tired that as `http://xxx.com/contactus.php?subject=a%20cat`. No go

Comment: My mistake you cannot simply fill the values to from by passing in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you url is `http://xxx.com/contactus.php?subject=a cat`

You can use `$_GET['subject']` to get to the value of subject.

So something like:

```
<label for=subject accesskey=S>Subject</label>
<select name="subject" type="text" id="subject">
<option value="a dog" <?php echo ($_GET['subject'] == 'a dog' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Dog</option>
<option value="a cat" <?php echo ($_GET['subject'] == 'a cat' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Car</option>
<option value="a tree" <?php echo ($_GET['subject'] == 'a tree' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>Tree</option>
</select>
```

Dont forget to use urlencode on your values and strip them before using in a query. Like so:

`http://xxx.com/contactus.php?subject=a%20cat` and `urlencode(stripslashes($_GET['subject']))`

Comment: Sorry, I think I am misunderstanding here. I do not wish to get the info. I would like to select the drop down from a URL. If I were to click on the link it would auto select a cat from the drop down menu, if you know what I mean. @Tim

Comment: Above answer solves ur question, if i am getting your question correct you want the drop down value to be based on the URL.

Comment: @Naveen Kumar - not quite. if I click on http://xxx.com/contactus.php?subject=a cat which would be a link on another page. It will come to contact us page and the DROP DOWN menu will be preselected with a cat opposed to the default setting.

Comment: Then in the contact us page get the value of subject like `$_GET['subject'] ` and make the appropriate dropdown selected as suggested above.